# Foundtry cast: (code: -32000, message: replacement transaction underpriced, data: None

Tags: foundry

Broadcasting a transaction with Foundry `cast` command fails with:

```
(code: -32000, message: replacement transaction underpriced, data: None
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 1):

This error message means that your RPC provider might have a stuck transaction in its mempool

- There is an ongoing transaction that might underpriced as the error message says
- This error message might be an artifact of some other issue your blockchain network (e.g. Polygon) is experiencing
- Validaotrs downprioritiseyour transaction because it is going to revert

You can attempt to fix this by casting harder, with `cast send --resend --priority-gas-price` flags.

- Check your blockchain explorer for the current priority gas price, e.g. [here for Polygon](https://polygonscan.com/gastracker)
- Then do `cast send --resend --priority-gas-price` with extra tip added for the validators